# Django form FileField can't pass a validation

Tags: python, django, forms, filefield

I see a lot of similar questions but can't found any answer. I need just to simply upload or process file using Django FileField. Here is what I have:

**forms.py**

```
class UploadForm(forms.Form):
    packet_file = forms.FileField()
```

**base.html**

```
<form action="process" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):

    form = UploadForm() # An unbound form
    return render(request, 'base.html', {'form': form})

def process(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid():
```

So the *index()* handles initial rendering of the empty form. When I fill it and it goes to *process()* it always returns

*This field is required.*

Next to the FileField form field.

What's wrong here? Am I missing any general Django settings like MEDIA files storage or so? Is it's even necessary at this phase when I can't validate form?

Thanks a lot
TC

Answer (score 2):

OK - it's my own stupidity as usual. I have two different applications and each one has its own sub-directory for templates. I thought Django uses that one within related directory first and when it's not found it goes to the project level.

But it doesn't work this way. So my I had two base.html templates for printing simple form, but the only the first one is being always called and it doesn't have *enctype="multipart/form-data"*

So that's it. Going back to study basic Django principles ;-)

Comment: ahah.. happened to me in the past... that's what I first looked: if you had enctype="multipart/form-data" :D